# Create conda env with qt v=5.9.0

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, conda

I am writing a script that calls an external SDK (C++ dll) that was developed using QT 5.9.0.

I am using Anaconda to manage Python environments, which currently comes with qt=5.9.7

When I call the SDK using ctypes:

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('path to the SDK')
```

I get entry point errors because of incompatible DLLs loaded when Python starts and the SDK.

I have a sloppy work-around where I created a folder with mixed DLLs that includes all the dependencies for the SDK with some DLLs from Python that miraculously takes care of the entry point errors, then I open the SDK from this folder. I have then successfully called functions from the SDK, so I know the SDK and my Python wrappers for the SDK work. But I do not like this work-around, especially because the SDK is still being developed, so my mixed folder will surely break at some point in the future.

I can use Anaconda Navigator to revert back to qt=5.9.4 or 5.6.2, but 5.9.0 is not an option.

I also tried to install the desired version using the command prompt (from within my env):

```
conda install qt=5.9.0
pip install qt==5.9.0
```

Both calls told me that the requested version/package is not available

Does this mean that qt=5.9.0 is not supported by Anaconda? Is there another way to get a Python environment that uses qt v5.9.0?

Thanks for any help/advice that you can provide!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that qt 5.9.0 is not available from the major Conda channels. _the SDK is still being developed_ Is this a private/internal project?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, it is a private/internal SDK over which I have no control.